# What is the difference between Composer business network and Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I understand that we can deploy multiple Hyperledger Composer Business networks on a fabric network with single Org (or multi org). Is it similar to deploying multiple chaincodes on a fabric network (on one or more channels)? That means, `composer network install` and `composer network start` are similar to `peer chaincode install` and `peer chaincode instantiate` on fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `composer network install` is similar to `peer chaincode install` as it installs your business network onto the peer (your business network is the chaincode here) and under the covers performs a request similar to the peer install command. `composer network start` is similar to `peer chaincode instantiate` as it makes a request to instantiate the business network chaincode but also performs some extra required activities specific to hyperledger composer.

Comment: Just a point is confusing to me. I still don't fully understand the difference between these two. Is it possible to implement a fabric network without 'business network' which one suppose to implement by composer or not? I mean writing a chaincode is enough or not.

The next question is about the alternative, the business network is the smart contract in abstracted layer, is it possible to have a blockchain network without any chaincode in the fabric layer? May deploying a business network (.js) is enough.

Comment: I think you should create a new stackoverflow entry for your question. It's not really the same as this one.